# What is the country code for Estonia on android phone

Tags: android, internationalization

What is the country code for Estonia on an Android  phone ?

For example French (France) is `fr_FR`
and Danish (Denmark) is `da_DK`

I opened a thread on Google Support but but nobody has replied yet.

[Google Support: What is the country code for estonia on Android?](http://GoogleSupport%3a%20what%20is%20the%20country%20code%20for%20estonia?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citing [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) from the dev guide:

> The language is defined by a two-letter ISO 639-1 language code, optionally followed by a two letter ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 region code (preceded by lowercase "r").

http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/english_country_names_and_code_elements.htm

> ESTONIA   EE

http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

> Estonian et

Answer (score 2):

I would go with et_EE but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html
There is not a predefined constant for Estonia
however

Being that they are based off the ISO standards `XX__XX` lowercase xx for language and upercase XX for country,

which come from the ISO lists:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes 
and 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2
respectively

it would be something like `et_EE` for Estonian in Estonia